# call python plugin on Jekyll post_write

Tags: ruby, jekyll

This feels like a `Jekyll` question, but might turn out to be simply a `Ruby` question...

### 1 background

- [hooks.feature](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/blob/master/features/hooks.feature) has helpful examples of `Jekyll::Hooks.register` usage, but intended to hook to `jekyll build`.
- I'm using a python script ([_plugins/compile_tags.py](https://github.com/harriott/harriott.github.io/blob/main/_plugins/compile_tags.py)) to generate my tag pages from the YAML front matter `tags` variable of my posts.
- I check my site locally with `bundle exec jekyll serve`.
- for testing, I've got `verbose: true` in my [_config.yml](https://github.com/harriott/harriott.github.io/blob/main/_config.yml)

### 2 wish: call python on post_write

Ray Fong hosts a Jekyll blog in which she explains how she automates the call to a python tag page creation script - [Automated Jekyll blog tags](https://rfong.github.io/rflog/2020/02/28/jekyll-tags/):

```rb
Jekyll::Hooks.register :posts, :post_write do
  system("python _plugins/compile_tags.py")
```

- and indeed it's here, [_plugins/compile_tags.rb](https://github.com/rfong/rflog/blob/master/_plugins/compile_tags.rb).
I'm assuming that while she's serving locally her site, this `Ruby` code calls her `Python` script to recreate tag pages as necessary.

### 3 the problem

Assuming Ray's Ruby plugin works as I suppose, I tried it myself, but no success - it never calls my python script. I tried tweaking it in various ways, including like this ([_plugins/compile_tags.rb](https://github.com/harriott/harriott.github.io/blob/main/_plugins/compile_tags.rb)),

```rb
Jekyll::Hooks.register :posts, :post_write do |post|
  puts 'post_write  was triggered in _plugins/compile_tags.rb'
  exec("python _plugins/compile_tags.py")
end
```

- still no luck - no message either...

### 4 my question

How can I have my `Python` script called during `jekyll serve` on hook `post_write`?

### 5 edit: hook partially working

Ray Fong encouraged me to do some tests, so I said `jekyll new minimal_test_site`, and in there made `_plugins/test.rb` containing the first example from [hooks.feature](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/blob/master/features/hooks.feature), and the hook was triggered as expected, (I got `_site/foo.html` containing the text "mytinypage"). So going back to my site, in my `Gemfile` I reverted from this:

```rb
 # Jekyll:
gem "github-pages", group: :jekyll_plugins  # bundle update github-pages
gem "webrick", "~> 1.7"  # instead of using Ruby v2.7.4,
 #  and still required even though  GitHub Pages  now uses  jekyll 3.9.3...
```

to this:

```rb
 # Jekyll:
gem "jekyll", "~> 4.3.2"
```

and, "Lo!" my hook gets called, but unfortunately it causes an unending loop of regenerating the tags, even when I change my `_plugins/compile_tags.rb` to `Jekyll` hook `after_reset`:

```rb
Jekyll::Hooks.register :site, :after_reset do
  puts '- infinite loop of tag generation...'
  system("python _plugins/compile_tags.py")
end
```

Maybe someone knows why...

Answer (score 0):

easily when you want to execute shell or python script(this case) in your ruby script, you can do this

```
`/pathto/pyhton your_python_script.py`

# or

%x(/pathto/pyhton your_python_script.py)

#or 

system(/pathto/pyhton your_python_script.py)
```

replace the "pathto" using this command in your shell

```
which python

/Users/myusername/opt/anaconda3/bin/python # on my laptop return this
```

so refer to your problem, this is the solution:

```
`/Users/myusername/opt/anaconda3/bin/python _plugins/compile_tags.py`

# or

%x(/Users/myusername/opt/anaconda3/bin/python _plugins/compile_tags.py)

# or 

system(/Users/myusername/opt/anaconda3/bin/python _plugins/compile_tags.py)
```

Comment: Good Ruby reply, and so I just went as far as trying `system("python /mnt/SDU3D1TB/Dropbox/JH/work/IT-Jekyll-harriott-minima/_plugins/compile_tags.py")` with no luck, as I expected. The point of the `Jekyll` `Plugins` directory ([Configuration Options](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/options/)) is that any `Ruby` code in there is run as necessary by a `jekyll serve` in the `Jekyll` site's root, so we shouldn't need an absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

Found this post while trying to fix the same problem, never-ending rebuild on trying to run an external script this way.

In the end I just wrote out a timestamp at the start of my script and compared to the current time each run. Then the script quits, not making any filesystem changes (not even update the timestamp) if was run in the last 10 seconds.

Bit of a "fudge" but it works :-)

Comment: Perhaps you could edit your answer with some code showing what you did, and elaborate on "not making any filesystem changes".